# Thread blocking issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, blocking

I have a problem with a threads or BeginInvoke's blocking the whole process of my data operations, I start threads or invokes like this

```
private void StartRetweetMarch(string twStatusId)
{
    foreach (var line in _emailBox.Lines)
    {

        //new Action<object>(Hashtags).BeginInvoke(new Email { twStatus = twStatusId, login = line.Split(':')[0], password = line.Split(':')[1] }, null, null);
        new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Hashtags)).Start(new Email { twStatus = twStatusId, login = line.Split(':')[0], password = line.Split(':')[1] });
        //_threads.Add(new Action<object>(Hashtags).BeginInvoke(new Email { login = line.Split(':')[0], password = line.Split(':')[1] }, null, null));
        //Thread.Sleep(40000);w
        // new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Hashtags)).Start(new Email { login = line.Split(':')[0], password = line.Split(':')[1] });
    }
}
```

But only first call of this foreach call, the other ones are pending or something like this, I don't know what to do.

Comment: How does the `Hashtags` method look like? Have you tried debugging your code and verified that the method actually is called only once? What is the blocked stack trace? (You can find that out by manually breaking the debugger and then looking at the call stack.) Aren't you getting an exception somewhere?

Comment: @svick here it is on PasteBin http://pastebin.com/XuZSpvuW

Comment: What about my other questions?

Comment: @svick yes, i tried to debug my code, Method is called so many times as *FIRST* foreach cycle starts it, i have no exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Inside of Hashtags method, it looks like not thread safe. For instance, _proxies variable, I'm not sure this type, but if you are just using List< string> type, then you have to write with exclusive lock.

```
//Outside of Method...
//Create lock Object
private static object _lock = new Object();

//Inside of Hashtags Method...
//exclusive lock. Inside of code block is thread safe. 
lock (_lock) {
    prox = _proxies[new Random().Next(0, _proxies.Count)];
    _proxies.Remove(prox);
}
```